# change recovery model on current database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to change the recovery model of the current database.

This is what I have:

```
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @dbName = DB_NAME()
ALTER DATABASE @dbName SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
```

`@dbName` gives me:

> Incorrect syntax near '@dbName'.

I tried:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_id SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
```

`database_id` gives me:

> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 3 User does not have permission to
>   alter database 'database_id', the database does not exist, or the
>   database is not in a state that allows access checks.

How should I execute this on the current database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'ALTER DATABASE ' 
  + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())
  + ' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```